# How to duplicate a source file in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

in visual studio 2019 on windows, if you right click on a .cs source file in the solution explorer, you have the option to copy. There is no duplicate option.  If you copy, there is no paste option.  There is no duplicate or paste in the file or edit menu either.  There is no ctrl-v option either.

Any ideas?

I cant find any way to add a source file either.  If I right click on the directory such as "blocks" where my current source files in my project are, then click "add", the menu which pops up "controller" is greyed out, as is "class".

There are no permissions issues - this is just a project I have been working on but is now "broken".  If I go to the root of the project in solution explorer, it has the option to create controllers for example, but bazarely not folders or classes.

If I create a new .cs file in one of the source folders using windows file explorer, there seems to be no option to get this new file picked up by visual studio.  The refresh icon at the top of the solution explorer is greyed out, and F5 does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, took me a while to figure this one out. Unlike every other IDE I have used for the last 20 years (eclipse, intellij etc), VS is for some reason making the entire project read only when its running locally.  I have to stop it running to be able to add files etc.